# Best method of uploading large files on server

Tags: php, file-upload, yii, yii2

I made an ajax based multiple file upload which is working well enough. But the issue is I have to upload very large files means upto 200 MB of file each and may be 20-25 files of same size at the same time. Files are being uploaded but it takes very long time to upload.

I have changed several things in php ini settings

```
post_max_size 10G
upload_max_size 10G
max_execution_time 3600
memory_limit -1
```

So what is the best solution for handling such type of file upload, which perform fast.

My internet connection is of 100 MB/S and upload speed with 20 MB/S.

Please suggest me some good solution.

Comment: Or initiate the upload as a background process, so you won't need to wait for the upload to complete and then do other stuff instead with upload being a background process you can do other stuff while the the files are uploaded in the background. **NOTE** This way is only feasible when you don't have to do stuff straight away with the uploaded files.

Comment: But what if i have to make it faster.

Comment: Hmm, if your upload speed is already 20 MB/s you really can't do nothing but to buy a faster upload connection. (If your upload speed is significantly slower than your max speed, I'd try to upload fewer files at the same time or change the script somehow.)

Answer (score 0):

From your application's point of view the only thing you can do is to limit the simultaneous file uploads. Extend your ajax multiple file upload script to upload just one file at a time. This probably will speed up things a little bit.

However your problem is probably not caused by the application itself, but by your server's network speed, or its disk writing speed. Some VPS providers also limits the number of disk write operations/sec. So, the best thing might be to migrate your app to another server with better network speed and performance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on wich type of file you're uploading, you can try to send a zipped file to the server and unzip it when the upload is finished.

You can see more about zip functions in php [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.zip.php).

To zip one file:
Source: http://davidwalsh.name/create-zip-php

```
    /* creates a compressed zip file */
function create_zip($files = array(),$destination = '',$overwrite = false) {
    //if the zip file already exists and overwrite is false, return false
    if(file_exists($destination) && !$overwrite) { return false; }
    //vars
    $valid_files = array();
    //if files were passed in...
    if(is_array($files)) {
        //cycle through each file
        foreach($files as $file) {
            //make sure the file exists
            if(file_exists($file)) {
                $valid_files[] = $file;
            }
        }
    }
    //if we have good files...
    if(count($valid_files)) {
        //create the archive
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        if($zip->open($destination,$overwrite ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {
            return false;
        }
        //add the files
        foreach($valid_files as $file) {
            $zip->addFile($file,$file);
        }
        //debug
        //echo 'The zip archive contains ',$zip->numFiles,' files with a status of ',$zip->status;

        //close the zip -- done!
        $zip->close();

        //check to make sure the file exists
        return file_exists($destination);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

To unzip files in the server:

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('file.zip');
if ($res === TRUE) {
  $zip->extractTo('/myzips/extract_path/');
  $zip->close();
  echo 'woot!';
} else {
  echo 'doh!';
}
?>
```

Comment: Sounds Something interesting in your script but my question is how to add records in database for each file and its info. Like file type, file size and file name. may be in zip format any one can upload any thing they want.

Answer (score -2):

The best way is to use old good FTP and some FTP clients like `FileZilla` for instance.

Comment: But those files are being added to site for downloads so we have to maintain database record of each file. So we cannot use FTP.

Comment: +1. FTP is, and always will be the easiest way for file transfer.
If you are the webmaster, you can create a database record for the new files in your bootstrap script on-the-fly. Just compare your database to your filesystem. Or, you might run a server-side daemon for file administration as well. Usually the best practice is to upload files with an offline method and do the administration in order to enable file download.